# Robocopy only copies files without folders

Tags: powershell, robocopy

The problem is: With this command, only files are copied, the folder structure is not copied. What can I do to fix it?

```
robocopy \\FSMTT2\P$ H: /J /MIR /COPYALL /ZB /W:5 /R:2 /XJ /XD "System Volume Information" "$Rec*" 
"Boot" /XF "pagefile.sys" /mT:128
```

The problem is: With this command, only files are copied, the folder structure is not copied. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Robocopy also has switches `/S` (copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.) and `/E` (copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.)

Comment: still skiping the folders i tried /s and /e

Comment: Try removing `/XD`

Comment: when i remove /XD it copies not only the folders i need but also lots of system files that i dont need

Comment: and if you add `/XA:SH`? See [File Attributes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) halfway on the page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `/MIR` not need to use `/COPYALL`.

Comment: Still skip folders :(

Comment: Can you remove  '/XJ /ZB' switches and then try.